# How to implement push notification in app being developed for Black Berry OS 6.0 using Phonegap and html5 framework like Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, blackberry, sencha-touch, push-notification

It is clearly stated in [Black Berry developer website](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/notification.html) that HTML5 notification is supported in Black Berry 10 only. Is there any way to implement push notification in app being developed for Black Berry OS 6.0 using Phonegap and html5 framework like Sencha Touch.

Any suggestions, workout examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this : https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications .
or this : http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/blackberry-html5-webworks-push-notification-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have you tried yourself or just it is your guess? Pushwoosh and phonegap plugin (you mentioned) uses html5 webworks to support notification in Black Berry. As Black Berry developer website clearly state that html5 notification do not support any version other than OS 10 i think it is not going to work. What do you say?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried. And if Pushwoosh uses HTML5 too, then it won't be helpful in your case. Search for some other methods for pushing like Active Sync or push over a socket connection over long ranged pings. There is one framework I'd come across for Active Sync : http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/ . Have a read.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter I have used its Javascript SDK and it was pretty easy. Read this if you want to use it with Sencha Touch http://www.pubnub.com/blog/building-a-pubnub-powered-chat-app-with-sencha-touch-2/